# How to column bind every n rows of a vector?

Tags: r, loops, datatables, tidyverse

I have a vector that is a 1100 elements long in sets of 11, 11x1000, I would like to split the data every 11th value and add this as a column to a data frame.
An example would be as follows:

```
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

such that the output would look as follows:

| Race 1 | Race 2 | Race 3 | Race 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |

I think this would work with a loop but have seen some tidy verse bits that might help however am unsure how to apply them.
Please let me know if this isn't clear!
Thanks in advance

Comment: `data.frame(matrix(vector, nrow = 3))` for this data, perhaps `data.frame(matrix(vector, nrow = 11))` for your larger data. You'll likely want to change the column names using `names` or `colnames`.

Comment: concise brilliance should likely be both an answer and explained as answered questions are the coin of the realm...for others, later.

Comment: @Chris: You are right. That is why It is [accepted at SO that you answer on behalf of others taking their (hidden) answer from a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat). So, if you feel like answering it yourself, read the post and go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` accepts `nrow=` as an argument, so the dimensions of the data can be controlled, then `data.frame(.)` wrapped around that converts it into a frame.

```r
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
data.frame(matrix(vector, nrow = 3))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
vector <- 1:33 # multiple of 11
data.frame(matrix(vector, nrow = 11))
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1   1 12 23
# 2   2 13 24
# 3   3 14 25
# 4   4 15 26
# 5   5 16 27
# 6   6 17 28
# 7   7 18 29
# 8   8 19 30
# 9   9 20 31
# 10 10 21 32
# 11 11 22 33
```